# Mysql data to Excel File

Tags: node.js, excel, reactjs, server, client

I am working on nodeJs and React, I have data in mysql storage.
ultimately i need to let the user to download the data in excel format.
Either we can do in nodeJs or React.
I tried to create a file in Node using excel4node package, The file gets created successfully, but when i send the file, it is not in excel format(some xml files and folders), i used downloadJs in frontend to  trigger  autoDownload.

```
router.get('/:year/:month', async (req, res, next) => {
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'Report.xlsx');
 res.sendFile(path.resolve('downloads/excel.xlsx'));
});
```

```
import downloadjs from 'downloadjs';

export const getReport = async (year, month) => {
  let res = await fetch(`${url}/get-report/${year}/${month}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
  })
  let blob = await res.blob();
  await downloadjs(blob);
};
```

This downloads a zip folder which has list of xml files.

I tried to create in React (client side) by sending json from the backend,
for this i used react-excel-workbook package, but it needs a predefined data, when we click, it suddenly gets downloaded with dummy data and it doesn't wait for async action to resolve.

Any help will be appreciated.

Or should i send the json from backend and on client side (convert it into csv and trigger download.??

Comment: what do you mean is not in Excel format? If the file is correct, and then you send it and it's not correct, obvs there's a problem with the sending function. Also, Excel reads CSV easily fyi

Comment: I've added few extra info, pls check.

Comment: That's because modern excel files ARE a bunch of xml zipped files :) . Try changing the Content-Type to application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: Its the same thing, even after changing content type.

Comment: All right, how about writing the excel directly to web and not an intermediate file?

Answer (score 0):

Write the file directly to the Response object, instead of going through an intermediate file

```
var xl = require('excel4node');
var wb = new xl.Workbook();
// sends Excel file to web client requesting the / route
// server will respond with 500 error if excel workbook cannot be generated
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  wb.write('ExcelFile.xlsx', res);
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: Still the downloaded is a zip folder.

Comment: Mmm I'm out of ideas, how about trying a different node package to generate the xls file?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you should specify content type when you are creating the blob in your frontend, then create a link in your DOM and specify to browser that the file must be downloaded :

```
    axios.get(`${your backend url goes here}/path/to/export`, {
            responseType: 'blob',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` //Or any auth method
            }
          }).then(res => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]), {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}); //specify CT
            const link = document.createElement('a'); // attach link to DOM
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'File.xlsx');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click(); // Auto dl the file
            link.remove(); // Remove the link
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
```